# Pasteboardmanager reference

Tags: cocoa, deprecated, macos-carbon, osx-leopard, pasteboard

HI i have an old code which uses a scrapref and selects scrap using GetScrapbyname(kscrapclipboardscrap,kscrapgetnamedscrap,&scrapref);

Than it takes the flavour count using getscrapflavourcount and then the list using getscrapinfoflavourlist

As the above API's are deprecated, i am trying to replace them using pasteboard manager

but to replace , getscrapflavourcount the replacement is PasteboardCopyItemFlavors which uses an itemid, which is not theer as such in the old code ??? what to do here ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa and `NSPasteboard` (plus `NSPasteboardItem` on 10.6+) would be the modern equivalents of the Pasteboard Manager (cf. [official documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008099) and [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CopyAndPaste) for examples).